# Normal probability distrubution.

Tags: statistics

any student who scores in the top 4% of students on the SMRT standardized exam. SMRT scores have a mean of 260 and a standard deviation of 22. What score does a student need to attain in order to receive the scholarship          worked problem this way.  1.00-.04=.96  which gave me z-score of .8315.  .8315*22+260=279  my worksheet says it should be 299.  can someone tell me where I went wrong.  thank you

Comment: The z-score for p=0.96 is $\approx1.75$.

Comment: this does not match my teachers worksheet answer of 299 and I don't understand how you came up with that answer.

Comment: Look here: https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~lzhou/stat302/standardnormaltable.pdf where p is approximately 0.96. Do you find the corresponding z-value ?

Comment: I'm sorry but why would I look on the neg side and that is 169. I thought I understood how to work this but now I am confused.  are you saying my teachers worksheet is wrong?

Comment: I dont know, which worksheet do you use. Do you have a link to it ? It is really a table about the standard normal distribution ? You can work with the negative side of the distribution. It is $\Phi(-z)=1-\Phi(z)$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the function of the standard normal distribution. In your case $\Phi(-z)=1-\Phi(z)\Rightarrow \Phi(-z)=1-0.96\Rightarrow \Phi(-z)=0.04$. Now you look at the linked table and find the z-value for p=0.04. This value is negative (-z). You have to take z.

Comment: Thank you after I post the last comment I seen what you were explaining, and I understand now.  Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear, that is all clear. Your are welcome.